# Format of Yolov7x configuration file not proper

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch, yolo

I am working on a project that classifies images as either covid infected or normal. I trained a yolov7x model using a custom dataset. After training, I downloaded the **bestWeights.pt** file and now I am trying to test the model by passing in new images as input to obtain predictions and bounding boxes on the input image.

**This is the approach that I am using with opencv:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Define the paths to the trained weights and model configuration files
weights_path = r'F:\Final_Year_Project\best.pt'
config_path = r'F:\Final_Year_Project\yolov7x-custom.yaml'

# Load the input image and convert it to a blob
image = cv2.imread(r'F:\Final_Year_Project\Covid_7.jpeg')
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1/255.0, (416, 416), swapRB=True, crop=False)

# Load the network and the class labels
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(weights_path, config_path)
classes = ['0', '1']  # Update this list with your own class labels


# Pass the blob through the network and get the detections
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()

# Iterate over the detections and extract the class probabilities
class_probabilities = []
for detection in detections:
    class_id = np.argmax(detection[5:])
    class_probability = detection[class_id+5]
    class_probabilities.append(class_probability)

# Convert the class probabilities to class labels
class_labels = [classes[i] for i in np.argmax(class_probabilities)]
print('Class labels:', class_labels)
```

[image: Error]
This is the error from the first approach

**I have searched for this everywhere and found out that this error occurs if the config file has some issues, but I am unable to find them**

**I am also attaching the config file here:**

```
# parameters
nc: 2  # number of classes
depth_multiple: 1.0  # model depth multiple
width_multiple: 1.0  # layer channel multiple

# anchors
anchors:
  - [12,16, 19,36, 40,28]  # P3/8
  - [36,75, 76,55, 72,146]  # P4/16
  - [142,110, 192,243, 459,401]  # P5/32

# yolov7 backbone
backbone:
  # [from, number, module, args]
  [[-1, 1, Conv, [40, 3, 1]],  # 0
  
   [-1, 1, Conv, [80, 3, 2]],  # 1-P1/2      
   [-1, 1, Conv, [80, 3, 1]],
   
   [-1, 1, Conv, [160, 3, 2]],  # 3-P2/4  
   [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [64, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -3, -5, -7, -8], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [320, 1, 1]],  # 13
         
   [-1, 1, MP, []],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [160, 1, 1]],
   [-3, 1, Conv, [160, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [160, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, -3], 1, Concat, [1]],  # 18-P3/8  
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -3, -5, -7, -8], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [640, 1, 1]],  # 28
         
   [-1, 1, MP, []],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [320, 1, 1]],
   [-3, 1, Conv, [320, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [320, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, -3], 1, Concat, [1]],  # 33-P4/16  
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -3, -5, -7, -8], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [1280, 1, 1]],  # 43
         
   [-1, 1, MP, []],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [640, 1, 1]],
   [-3, 1, Conv, [640, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [640, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, -3], 1, Concat, [1]],  # 48-P5/32  
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -3, -5, -7, -8], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [1280, 1, 1]],  # 58
  ]

# yolov7 head
head:
  [[-1, 1, SPPCSPC, [640]], # 59
  
   [-1, 1, Conv, [320, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],
   [43, 1, Conv, [320, 1, 1]], # route backbone P4
   [[-1, -2], 1, Concat, [1]],
   
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -3, -5, -7, -8], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [320, 1, 1]], # 73
   
   [-1, 1, Conv, [160, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],
   [28, 1, Conv, [160, 1, 1]], # route backbone P3
   [[-1, -2], 1, Concat, [1]],
   
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -3, -5, -7, -8], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [160, 1, 1]], # 87
      
   [-1, 1, MP, []],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [160, 1, 1]],
   [-3, 1, Conv, [160, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [160, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, -3, 73], 1, Concat, [1]],
   
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -3, -5, -7, -8], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [320, 1, 1]], # 102
      
   [-1, 1, MP, []],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [320, 1, 1]],
   [-3, 1, Conv, [320, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [320, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, -3, 59], 1, Concat, [1]],
   
   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [512, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -3, -5, -7, -8], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [640, 1, 1]], # 117
   
   [87, 1, Conv, [320, 3, 1]],
   [102, 1, Conv, [640, 3, 1]],
   [117, 1, Conv, [1280, 3, 1]],

   [[118,119,120], 1, IDetect, [nc, anchors]],   # Detect(P3, P4, P5)
  ]
```

Comment: that doesn't look like a *darknet* cfg file

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you please elaborate? What does it look like and if its wrong where can I get the correct one from? Thanks